# What domain name should we use with this.passthrough() in mirage js to enable API call to cloud Firestore?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, miragejs

I am trying to make an API call to my data in cloud Firestore but I have mirage js, too. Now I am getting error where the backend doesn't respond to my call.

This one is not working:

```
this.passthrough("https://firestore.googleapis.com/**")
```

> bundle.js:160016 [2023-10-05T02:34:04.528Z] @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.4.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds. This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

Comment: bundle.js:160016 [2023-10-05T02:34:04.528Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.4.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.